Screenshot of the Week #121
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 121st edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Elements In Space's screenshot from day-of-the-tentacle won with 12 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-08-06, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-08-12, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Just a cute little-kitty-big-city


..smelling something nasty?

No smells something fishy

@Joachim Actually rubbing it's face on the camera before the player takes control.

Oh, that's cool!

And reminded me of something :)

@Joachim you really love cats am I right?

I see cat, I upvote.

Cuddle time for our little buddy in rime


Not a dog but: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJiOhgte56OrUVyne3C4HdStrnowE7bLwulQ&s

A spacious (but catless) Karnacian interior in dishonored-2:


Damn, now that's something I wish I could visit in VR

"Work safely today. Remember... someone expects you home tomorrow"
dead-space


It just came to me that there's plenty of toilets in Dead Space too. There's even articles online speculating why the toilets are the scariest place of the game.

The reason, I reckon, is that toilets are one of the most basal and private places in our daily lives, where we bare our weaknesses. Through association, finding them in a place that has been infested with mutated undead corpses that can pop up anywhere is the stuff of nightmares.

@Joachim sounds like it would have been fitting for last weeks theme!

@TimmyJim Definitely! A toilet from which mutated things jump would have gone well with the Giger toilet! (And writing that just now reminded me of toilets in Bioshock and Prey (and then Deus Ex, probably for being able to creep around toilets yourself). But two weeks ago my head wasn't in it. Figuratively.)

I feel targeted.  I've got back protection and lifting training for work that I'm completing right now.

@MBraedley You mean you're currently working in a physically very demanding environment?

No, much like the poster, the training is basically meaningless for my job.  I'm a developer, the heaviest things I lift are my laptop and coffee mug.

@MBraedley Coffee is the most important tool for developers (I'm a developer, so I understand)

@Wondercricket https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.1915509370.9292/flat,750x,075,f-pad,750x1000,f8f8f8.jpg

The hope of the fayth's in final-fantasy-10

Just a little more; and maybe you are the dream who will end our dreaming at last.

"You'll cry. You're gonna cry. You always cry. See? You're crying."

When i played IT the First time i was shocked Here. This zanarkand a dream and me too
